# Graph theory: 2 small problems

Tags: graph-theory

- Consider a graph $\Gamma$ of order $n \ge 3$, with $n-1$ different degrees. There has to be exactly one number $i$ that is the degree of exactly two vertices. What are the possible values of $i$?

My attempt: The graph has order $n$, so for the degree $k$ of a vertex of this graph we have $0 \le k \le n-1$ (antireflexive!). However the values $0$ and $n-1$ cannot occur at the same time. So the possible values of the occurring degrees are $\{0,\dots,n-2\}$ or (exclusive) $\{1,\dots, n-1\}$. This means that we can always guarantee that $1 \le i \le n-2$, which - I believe - is the answer.

- How many non-isomorphic graphs of order $n$ are there with exactly $n-1$ different degrees?

My attempt: This one is harder. Consider two graphs $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$. I know that if 1) $|V(\Gamma_1)| \ne |V(\Gamma_2)|$, 2) $|E(\Gamma_1)| \ne |E(\Gamma_2)|$ or 3) $\exists v \in V(\Gamma_1): \deg_{\Gamma_1}(v) \ne \deg_{\Gamma_2} (\phi(v))$, the two graphs are not isomorphic. Like in the bullet, we know that the possibilities of the value of the vertex degrees are $\{0,\dots,n-2\}$ or $\{1,\dots, n-1\}$.

In both cases there will be $n!$ possible graphs ($n \cdot (n-1) \cdot \dots \cdot 1$), so that makes a total of $2 \cdot n!$. I don't know how to find out whether or not I've included isomorphic graphs in this total.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the degrees of all the vertices has to be even.  If $n$ is odd this will rule out some possible values of $i$.  For example, if $n=5$ you could have vertices with degrees $0,1,2,3$ or $1,2,3,4$.  The sum of both of these sets is even, so the last vertex must have even degree.  It can't be $0$ in the first case because you couldn't have a vertex of degree $3$, so it must be $2$.  In the second case you can't have two vertices of degree $4$ because of the one with degree $1$, so again the degree that must be duplicated is $2$.  For $n=4$ you can have degrees $0,1,2$, which sums to $3$ so the duplicated degree must be odd and therefore $1$.  If you have degrees $1,2,3$ the sum is even and the duplicated degree must be $2$.

I would draw graphs for $n=6$ and $7$ to try and see if you have choices.

Comment: I think I found something: for $n$ even, $i = n/2$ and for $n$ odd, $i = (n-1)/2$. I've done this by drawing the graphs for $n=6,7$ like you suggested, but is there a formal way to prove this?

Comment: My example for $n=4$ gave two choices, $\frac n2-1$ and $\frac n2$.  Look again at your $n=6$ case with the $0$ vertex.  I think you can prove it by considering the complementary graph.  It will have the same form, but with the other degree sequence.